# Chrome: run snippet from bookmark bar

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, code-snippets, bookmarklet

Snippet:

`Name: run_test`

```
alert('test')
```

If drag-drop from snippets pane to bookmark bar i get a bookmark with its name and
`snippet:///run_test` as URL, but it is not doing anything when pressed
Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

A URL starting with `snippet:` is not a valid URL in order to make it run
`alert('test')`
You would change it to `javascript: alert('test')`